# What is the difference between the results of atom.GetIdx() and Chem.CanonicalRankAtoms()?

Tags: python, rdkit

In the RDKit docs it is said that the `rdkit.Chem.rdChem.GetIdx(Atom atom)` returns the atom's index according to the molecule.

[Docs: Chem.rdchem.Atom.GetIdx](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.Chem.rdchem.html#rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Atom.GetIdx)

Also `rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles.CanonicalRankAtoms (Mol mol)` returns the canonical ranking of the atoms in the molecule.

[Docs: Chem.rdmolfiles.CanonicalRankAtoms](http://rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles.html?highlight=pdb#rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles.CanonicalRankAtoms)

My question is how is the atom's canonical rank different from the atom's index?

```
`moleculeSmiles = "C1NCN1"
 mol1 = Chem.AddHs(Chem.MolFromSmiles(moleculeSmiles))
 rankList = list (rdmolfiles.CanonicalRankAtoms(mol1))
 atomIdxList  = []
 for atom in atomIter:
    atomIdxList.append(atom.GetIdx())   
 print (atomIdxList)
 print (rankList)`
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[8, 6, 9, 7, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 1]
```

Comment: As the function name would suggest the CanonicalRankAtoms function returns the canonical atom ranking for each atom. The function uses the algorithm published in [this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/acs.jcim.5b00543).

Comment: Could you tell me on what basis do they number the atoms in the atom.GetIdx() process?

Comment: If you are creating an rdkit Mol from an SDF the atom indexes are conserved, I assume this is the same for SMILES

Comment: And is the indexing done on the basis of anything particular?

Comment: The ***atom indexes are conserved***. If we consider an SDF file atom index 0 corresponds to the first atom specified within the SDF and atom index 1 corresponds to the second....